# How do I get my program to loop the program if yes and if no exit the program and print

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple to-do list with java. It asks the user to enter an item, adds that to the list, then asks if they want to enter more items. If it's yes they it prompts them to enter more items and runs again, if no it will print out the list and end the program. 
My code so far is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoDriver
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     ToDoList list = new ToDoList();

     System.out.println("Enter items for the list when prompted.");
     System.out.println("Add Item:");

     String task = input.nextLine();
     list.add(task);
     boolean more;

        System.out.println("Do you wish to add more items?");
        more = Boolean.parseBoolean(input.nextLine());
        while(more == true)
        {
         System.out.println("Do you wish to add more items?");
         more = Boolean.parseBoolean(input.nextLine());

         System.out.println("Add Item: ");
         task = input.nextLine();
         list.add(task);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code work as intended? If no, what happens instead?

Comment: also just do while(more) instead of while(more == true) as more already is a boolean

Comment: It just runs once then when it asks if you want to enter more items whether you put yes or no it exits

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you want. Note that you will have to say "Yes" or it will not continue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ToDoList list = new ToDoList();

        boolean stillAdding = false;
        String task;
        String continuing;

        System.out.println("Enter items for the list when prompted.");
        do {
            System.out.println("Add Item:");
            task = input.nextLine();
            list.add(task);
            System.out.println("Do you wish to add more items?");
            continuing = input.nextLine();
            if (continuing.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") {
                stillAdding = true;
            } else {
                stillAdding = false;
            }
       } while (stillAdding)
       System.out.println("Done adding");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome. But how would I go about getting it to end the program and print out the list if they say "No"?

Comment: you have to add else condition to set stillAdding = false

Comment: @sahil0021 Thanks, I can't believe I forgot that